# When is a fraction simplified?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

When is a fraction simplified?

*"A fraction is simplified if the numerator and denominator do not have any common factors other than 1."*

This is what I read on this website: http://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/beg_algebra/beg_alg_tut3_fractions.htm

I think a fraction is simplified when the numerator or denominator have common factors other than 1. 
For example: $\frac {14} 6 = \frac73$

Comment: "It 'is' already simplified" and "it 'is' to be simplified". Seems to be your problem.

Comment: @exploringnet can you answer my question?

Comment: I have not fully understood what problem do you have , but think you have been confused by the language.

Comment: 7 and 3 have no common factors other than 1.

Comment: We can simplify a fraction when its numerator and denominator have any common factor other than 1. But the website says "When they do not have any common factors other than 1."

Comment: @SamamaFahim You are getting confused with the example given. You 'can' simplify a fraction but the definition says "A fraction 'is' simplified......"

Comment: @Isp Yeah I got that....! I got confused because in the title there it was written 'When is a fraction simplified?" So I thought that it could be the situation when a fraction has to be simplified.. It was the language problem sorry!

Comment: It happens sometimes when you are too much into the mathematics and ignore the English !! :)

Comment: Sometimes there is the further convention that the denominator is chosen to be positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "A fraction **is** simplified if the numerator and denominator do not have any common factors other than 1."

The **is** used here says that it **is**(currently) simplified, already simplified.

Whereas

> "I  think a fraction **is** simplified when the numerator or denominator have common factors other than 1. For example: $14/6=7/3$"

Here **is** means it is(needs to be) simplified when it is not.

Comment: Most of the time english confuses me too.

Comment: I don't think that your explanation of the second sentence  is correct. Can you give other examples of such usage in English to support that meaning?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused between "A fraction 'is' simplified" and "A fraction 'can' be simplified".

In the example that you provided:

$\dfrac{7}{3}$ is the **'simplified fraction'** and $\dfrac{14}{6}$ is the fraction that is getting simplified to $\dfrac{7}{3}$.

The example is given to make you understand that $\dfrac{14}{6}$ is simplified to $\dfrac{7}{3}$ and it cannot be simplified further making it a **'simplified fraction'**